# .Net async Socket multi-threaded sending

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, networking

i have a socket, im using to send large buffers through, if ill do something like

```
// may be accsed form a a lot of threads
void Send(byte[] buffer)
{
  m_socket.BeginSend(buffer ... , SendCallback);
}

void SendCallback()
{
  m_socket.EndSend()

  // if not done sending- send the reset
  m_socket.BeginSend()
}
```

my question is: will this work from a multithreading stand point, or will the buffers interleave?

Comment: Can you be clearer about the API you are using? I don't see a Socket.Send() overload that matches your call.

Comment: sorry got the function name wrong, ive edited. im using :
  public IAsyncResult BeginSend(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting MSDN:

> If you perform multiple asynchronous
>   operations on a socket, they do not
>   necessarily complete in the order in
>   which they are started.

But if you are sending blocks of data from multiple threads, what is your definition of 'order' anyway?

Comment: if i have to messages: "aaaa" and "bbbb" i wont the reciver to get: "aaaabbbb" or "bbbbaaaa", but not "aabbaabb" if the socket's sending buffer is 2 bytes big.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is thread-safe.

Since your delegate to "SendCallback" is executed on a new thread, I would presume that EndSend() can tell which asynchronous operation you are ending based on the current thread context.

See the MSDN "Best Practices" for the asynchronous programming model:

```
Simultaneously Executing Operations

If your class supports multiple concurrent invocations, enable the developer to track each invocation separately by defining the MethodNameAsync overload that takes an object-valued state parameter, or task ID, called userSuppliedState. This parameter should always be the last parameter in the MethodNameAsync method's signature.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228974.aspx